# Generate RMI classes in Java5 and Server Code in Java6 using Ant

Tags: java, ant, rmi

I'm currently migrating our system to Java6.  But most of our RMI clients are in Java5.  I want to keep the server running on Java6 so I can use those features but I cannot get the clients to upgrade to Java6.  Is there a way in our ant build process to compile the server code under 6 and generate Java5 RMI jars?  I'm not familiar with how to build it in ant.  It currently compiles everything and then jars up the client code for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Without details of build.xml it hard to be more specific, but this is done via setting target-attribute of [javac-task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).

example

```
<target name="compile-rmi">
    <javac target="1.5" src="path-to-rmi-sources" destdir="rmi-classes"/>
</target>
<target name="compile-other-stuff">
    <javac target="1.6" src="path-to-other-stuff-sources"/>
</target>
```

Then you go and use [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) to result of compile-rmi and build separate jar with something like this:

```
  <jar destfile="my-rmi.jar" basedir="rmi-classes"/>
```